# Easy way to convert &#XXXX; from HTML to UTF-8 xml either programmaticaly in .Net or using tools

Tags: .net, html, xml, utf-8

HTML and XML are not same just given for illustration.

For input HTML file

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='tab-stops:.5in'><b><span style='mso-tab-count:3'>                                    </span></b><b><span
lang=AR-SY dir=RTL style='mso-bidi-language:AR-SY'>&#1593;&#1586;&#1578;
&#1575;&#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1607;&#1610;&#1605;
&#1575;&#1604;&#1583;&#1608;&#1585;&#1610;</span><o:p></o:p></b></p>
```

receive XML with UTF-8 encoding

```
<Name Type="Script"> صدام حسين التكريتي</Name>
```

Basically I need a sequence ASCII sequence &#xxxx;&#yyyy;&#zzzz; to be saved as utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if you want to convert the HTML decimal encoding in place or do a transformation from HTML to an XML document. Converting the decimal (or hexadecimal) encoded characters to UTF-8/16 is not too difficult. However, properly parsing HTML in the wild can be a challenge (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).

Here is a naive class for converting decimal and hexadecimal encoded characters in place and returning a .Net string (I make no guarantees about its correctness or robustness - particularly if you are trying to use it against malformed HTML or have surrogate pair characters):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HtmlEncodingConverter
{
    internal static class HtmlEncoding
    {
    private static readonly Regex EncodedCharRegex = new Regex(@"&#[X]?[0-9|A-F]{1,12};",
                                                               RegexOptions.Compiled |
                                                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |
                                                               RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);


    public static string ToUtfCharacters(string input)
    {
        return ConvertInnerText(input, ReplaceWithCharacter);
    }

    private static string ReplaceWithCharacter(string original)
    {
        return EncodedCharRegex.Replace(original, new MatchEvaluator(DecodeCharacter));
    }

    private static string DecodeCharacter(Match match)
    {
        string digits = match.ToString().TrimStart(new[] {'#', '&'}).TrimEnd(';').ToUpperInvariant();
        return digits.StartsWith("X") ? HexToString(digits) : DecToString(digits);
    }

    private static string DecToString(string digits)
    {
        return ((char) int.Parse(digits)).ToString();
    }

    private static string HexToString(string digits)
    {
        return ((char) int.Parse(
            digits.Substring(1), 
            NumberStyles.HexNumber, 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString();
    }

    private static string ConvertInnerText(string original, Func<string, string> converter)
    {
        var convertedQueue = new Queue<char>(original.Length);
        var innerQueue = new Queue<char>();
        int tagCount = 0;
        bool hasFoundHtml = false;
        foreach (char character in original)
        {
            if (character.Equals('<'))
            {
                hasFoundHtml = true;
                if (tagCount == 0 && innerQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    var innerString = new string(innerQueue.ToArray());
                    string convertedString = converter.Invoke(innerString);
                    foreach (char convertedCharacter in convertedString)
                    {
                        convertedQueue.Enqueue(convertedCharacter);
                    }
                    innerQueue.Clear();
                }
                tagCount += 1;
                convertedQueue.Enqueue(character);
                continue;
            }
            if (character.Equals('>'))
            {
                tagCount -= 1;
                convertedQueue.Enqueue(character);
                continue;
            }
            if (tagCount == 0 && hasFoundHtml)
            {
                innerQueue.Enqueue(character);
            }
            else
            {
                convertedQueue.Enqueue(character);
            }
        }
        return new string(convertedQueue.ToArray());
    }
}
}
```