# How to create special character string in vb.net

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding

In ancient time, we can specify all characters with `chr(56)`

For example, say the character is unprintable. We want to put it in a string. Just do

```
Dim a as string = chr (56)
```

Now we have UTF8 or unicode (or whatever encoding).

Say I want variable a to contain

```
 &#8194;    &ensp;      en space
 &#8195;    &emsp;      em space
 &#8201;    &thinsp;    thin space
‌ &#8204;    &zwnj;      zero width non-joiner
‍ &#8205;    &zwj;       zero width joiner
‎ &#8206;    &lrm;       left-to-right mark
 &#8207;    &rlm;       right-to-left mark
```

In fact, say I want to create a function that'll get rid all of such characters from my string.

How would I do so?

I want the function to leave chinese, korean, japanese characters intact and then get rid really really vague ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace) removes whatever you want. [ChrW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw) produces Unicode characters by code (to produce characters outside Unicode Plane 0 you need to concatenate 2 Char).

Something like:

```
Replace("My text", ChrW(8194), "");
```

Comment: Are you sure? I thought unicode contains far more than 65k characters and ChrW simply handle around 65k character

Comment: String are UTF-16, if you need other Unicode characters outside Plane 0 you just need to concat 2 Char to form whole Unicode character - check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697055/c-sharp-and-utf-16-characters and description of planes at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29

Answer (score 1):

```
''' <summary>
''' This function replaces 'smart quotes' (ASC 145, 146, 147, 148, 150) with their correct ASCII versions (ASC 39, 34, 45), and replaces any other non-ASCII characters with "?"
''' </summary>
''' <param name="expression"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function Unicode2ASCII(ByVal expression As String) As String
  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
  For i As Integer = 1 To Len(expression)
    Dim s As String = Mid(expression, i, 1)
    Select Case Asc(s)
      Case 145, 146 'apostrophes'
        sb.Append("'"c)
      Case 147, 148 'inverted commas'
        sb.Append(""""c)
      Case 150 'hyphen'
        sb.Append("-"c)
      Case Is > 127
        sb.Append("?"c)
      Case Else
        sb.Append(s)
    End Select
  Next i
  Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Or to add them...

```
Dim s As String = "a" & ChrW(8194) & "b"
MsgBox(s)
```

Comment: I really do not think this will work. All you do is just look at the asc. We're talking  about far more special characters than just these.

Comment: Actually, if you change to AscW() you can strip out or replace the characters you want. Unless you are talking about adding them? In which case use Char.ConvertFromUtf32() or ChrW()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there ought to be a better way, but the best I can come up with that would work in all situations would be something like this:

```
Private Function getString(ByVal xmlCharacterCode As String) As String
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><test>" + xmlCharacterCode + "</test>")
    Return doc.InnerText
End Function
```

And then use it like this:

```
myString = myString.Replace(getString("&#8194;"), "")
```

Also, you may want to take a look at this page I found:

[Easy way to convert &#XXXX; from HTML to UTF-8 xml either programmaticaly in .Net or using tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393153/easy-way-to-convert-xxxx-from-html-to-utf-8-xml-either-programmaticaly-in-ne)